# Finding $f$ such that $f(xy) = xf(y)+yf(x)-2xy$ given $f'(1)=3$

Tags: functions

Let $f$ be a differentiable function satisfying the relation                $$f(xy) = xf(y)+yf(x)-2xy$$ where $x, y>0$ and $f'(1)=3$ then prove that the equation f(x) = k has two solutions in
 $k\in(-e^{-3}, 0)$

I tried differentiating this function but couldn't get anything from it. How to proceed here?

Comment: please edit the equation correctly, i don't understand what it says

Comment: Is it legible now?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can compute $f$ explicitly. Let $g(x)=\frac {f(x)} x -2$ and verify that $g(xy)=g(x)+g(y)$. Do you know how to find all continuous functions satisfying this equation?. [$f(x)=x(c\log\, x+2)$].

Comment: I am ashamed to say I don't understand what you did. Can you tell me more about how you wrote the equation

Comment: @GENESECT You can easily guess that dividing the given equation by $xy$ brings it to a more manageable form. After this I just adjusted for the the constant term.

Comment: @kavi ram murty Sir can i find this kind of promblems in the book of functional equation written by 'b j venkatachala'

Comment: I am sure you will find similar problem in Vektachala's book.

Comment: I deleted my answer. It was a Calculation mistake,no D.E. can be obtained by just differentiating i guess. By the way in your answer how do you find all the continuos solution? (I dont know how to do that , i am sorry )

Answer (score -1):

Hint: you can compute f explicitly. Let g(x)=f(x)x−2 and verify that g(xy)=g(x)+g(y). Do you know how to find all continuous functions satisfying this equation?. [f(x)=x(clogx+2)].